# How to git a mysql database made on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, git, path, phpmyadmin

I would like to use git on a database made with phpmyadmin for use it with my collaborators. Is there a way to use git together with phpmyadmin? If yes I have not found it through the web, so I would llike to init git in the folder where the database is stored, but I can't find this directory, where could it be? I'm working on ubuntu 13.10.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you rate down my question, can you write the motivation please? They can be useful for me.

Comment: A quick search on the web yields this: https://deveo.com/blog/2013/06/19/your-git-repository-in-a-database-pluggable-backends-in-libgit2/

Comment: @flyx, I don't think the OP is asking about storing git metadata in a database -- they want the reverse, to store a database as git data.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend exporting the database (under the **Export** tab in phpMyAdmin), and store the exported form of your database as a flat file a directory you create as a git repo. Re-export when you want.

This also gives you the flexibility to export a specific database instead of the whole system. Just highlight the database you want to export before you click on the **Export** tab.

It's really not the intended use of git (or any distributed source control system) to store binary files. There's no way to merge them, so files just overwrite rather than merge. Add to this pushes from other people's local repos, and it just becomes a mess of people clobbering each others' work.

Also the data files in your data directory are updating continually. They would not update the committed copy in git until you do a `git commit`. There's no guarantee that you'd commit these files in a safe manner. That is, you could save the last table a few seconds later than the first table, and then you'd have an inconsistent snapshot of the data.

To ensure a consistent export, you'd have to make sure no applications are making any changes, or else lock all tables.

But to answer your question, you can find out the location of a given MySQL instance's data directory in phpMyAdmin, by clicking the **Variables** tab, and searching for the variable **datadir**. The value of that variable is the location of your data directory on the MySQL server.